# CSRF Token validation | Ruby | Rake | PUT |

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, csrf, put

I am trying to update data using a PUT web service against a particular id. So my json request is something like

```
{
    id: 1,
    status: 'A'
}
```

My web service expects a CSRF Token. So i first do a GET using the same url and passing the header parameter and value as

```
x-csrf-token => 'fetch'
```

The GET gives me a token, which i then pass in my request header for PUT, but still i get a CSRF Token validation failed.

I am doing the GET and the PUT in a RAKE task (of course using Ruby on rails).

Ruby version 2.0.0
Rails version 4.0.0

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks
Abhishek

Comment: please write your code you are using to get csrf token..?

Comment: first thought from the top of my head - once you do a `GET` request and recive the token the session is not stored. Then doing another request creates a new session and a new token and validation fails.

Comment: @radical_edo Thanks, so, do i need to store the csrf token in session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Rails's code

```
  # Returns true or false if a request is verified. Checks:
  #
  # * is it a GET or HEAD request?  Gets should be safe and idempotent
  # * Does the form_authenticity_token match the given token value from the params?
  # * Does the X-CSRF-Token header match the form_authenticity_token
  def verified_request?
    !protect_against_forgery? || request.get? || request.head? ||
      form_authenticity_token == params[request_forgery_protection_token] ||
      form_authenticity_token == request.headers['X-CSRF-Token']
  end

  # Sets the token value for the current session.
  def form_authenticity_token
    session[:_csrf_token] ||= SecureRandom.base64(32)
  end
```

The way I see it. If on your `GET` request you'll store token in `session[:_csrf_token]` and then pass it in your another request in `params[:authenticity_token]` (default) you should be fine.